# Test state value after promise resolved

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, mobx, mobx-react

Given an component that make a login ...

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { userStore, data } = this.props;

  this.setState({isLogin: true});

  const promise = userStore.login(data);
  promise.then(() => {
    this.setState({isLogin: false});
  })
}
```

How can I create a test that validate if isLogin state is false after the promise is resolved?

So far, I have ..

```
it('resolved submit should set isLogin to false', () => {
  mockApi.onPost('/authenticate').reply(200);

  const userStore = new UserStore();
  let fromPromiseLogin;
  userStore.login = jest.fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce((data) => {
        fromPromiseLogin = userStore.login(data);
        return fromPromiseLogin;
     });
  const wrapper = mount(
    <FormLogin userStore={userStore} />,
  );

  wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');

  // HOW CAN I WAIT/OR CALLBACK FOR THE PROMISE ? I TRIED >
  whenWithTimeout(
    () => fromPromiseLogin && fromPromiseLogin.state !== PENDING,
    () => expect(wrapper.state().isLogin).toBeFalsy(),
  );

});
```

But a exeption

> [mobx] Encountered an uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[When@21] TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
This answer is no longer relevant after the question has been edited.

---

Have you tried to test the result of the promise with `.resolves` function as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#resolves)?

```
expect(myPromise).resolves.toEqual('SomeValue');
```

Or using [async/await](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#async-await):

```
const result = await myPromise;
expect(result).toEqual('SomeValue');
```

Comment: How would you get `myPromise` in the test? Unless the returned it from `onSubmit` but then you would be modifying the code just to test?